# MS Form not displaying in Edge Browser

Tags: sharepoint-online, iframe, embedded, edge

We are embedding a MS Form within a Modern SharePoint page and it works perfectly fine in Google Chrome but this error is displaying when viewing the same page in MS Edge . Any ideas on how to resolve this or are MS Forms not supported in MS Edge?!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use SharePoint Online?

Per my test, the Microsoft Forms can display in Edge when I use Embed web part in modern page. How did you embed the MS form?

Besides, there is a Microsoft Forms web part in Modern page, you can use it to test again.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm using, the MS Forms Modern Webpart. When I toggle the webpart to "Show form results", it loads. But when I select the radio button "Collect responses", I get the error shown in the OP

Comment: even in chrome I get the error when I toggle it to collect response